# Papaja: Vertical Distance Between Paragraphs

Tags: papaja

Compiling the following RMarkdown document in which I use the `doc` mode of the `apa6` class.

```
---
linenumbers       : no

documentclass     : "apa6"
classoption       : "doc"
output            : papaja::apa6_pdf
---

# Methods
We report how we determined our sample size, all data exclusions (if any), all manipulations, and all measures in the study. 

Next paragraph
```

leads to
[image]

Thus, vertical space is added when a new paragraph is started.

**I don't want this, and my question is how to prevent it.**

Looking into the produced `.tex` file, I found that `papaja` modifies `\parksip` in the latex header.

```
\@ifundefined{KOMAClassName}{% if non-KOMA class
  \IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
    \usepackage{parskip}
  }{% else
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}}
}{% if KOMA class
  \KOMAoptions{parskip=half}}
```

Removing this from the `.tex` produces the desired result:

[image]

However, this is, of course, a rather hacky solution. I would much prefer to tell `papaja` not to modify `\parskip`. I  also don't understand why it is doing this, as it seems to conflict with the APA rules it is trying to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use header includes. The following additional lines in your YAML header should yield the desired behavior:

```
header-includes:
 - \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
```

The code basically overrides the modifications that you described above.

Comment: Thanks for the fast help! Just out of curiosity: Since you are one of the co-authors of `papaja`, why do you modify `\parskip`?

Comment: I think this is not papaja-specific, but a feature of the `apa6` LaTeX class.